# JSF viewParam doesnt work with CDI

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

I'm trying to make my page bookmarkable, but it doesnt work. Here is the code:

```
   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam id="id" name="id" value="#{myBean.id}" />
       <f:event type="preRenderView"  listener="#{myBean.preRenderView}" />
    </f:metadata>
```

`MyBean.java`:

```
@Named("myBean")
@ConversationScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

   private Object id; //get set

   public void preRenderView()   {

       if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {   
           //test....
       }
   }
}
```

When the `page.jsf?id=3` is called from the browser, the method is called, but the param is not set. Someone knows what is wrong?

Comment: So.. Exactly the same code works fine when you replace `@Named @ConversationScoped` by `@ManagedBean @ViewScoped`? That's namely what your question title is implying. If that's true, you're going to need to tell something more about the JSF and CDI implementation/version being used (and if unsure, preferably also the application server implementation/version).

Comment: What do you do to check if the property is set or not. `@ConversationScoped` behaves roughly like a request scope if didn't start a conversation. Also, I don't know how JSF behaves when it finds a binding to an `Object` property, you should try with a `String` or a numeric type.

Comment: The same code doesnt work neither with @ManagedBean neither String or numeric type. I'm using Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) and  WELD-000900 1.1.5 (AS71).

Comment: My guess is that it actually is getting set, or at least trying to set it, you didn't say anything about exceptions, but because you're not promoting your conversation to a long running conversation it's destroyed at the end of the request. Have you added any break points  to see if things really are being called?